# How do I cast a Bloomberg DateTime to System.DateTime

Tags: c#, casting, bloomberg

What is the preferred way to cast a BBG DateTime to normal System?

```
DateTime px_close_dt = (DateTime) fields.GetElementAsDatetime("PX_CLOSE_DT");
```

Bloomberglp.Blpapi.DateTime is returned...

This gives cast error

Comment: @Habib it returns a Bloomberglp.Blpapi.DateTime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the method [`ToSystemDateTime();`](http://static.bloomberglabs.com/api/dotnet/doc/3.8/) like:

```
DateTime px_close_dt = fields.GetElementAsDatetime("PX_CLOSE_DT").ToSystemDateTime();
```

See: [DateTime.ToSystemDateTime](http://static.bloomberglabs.com/api/dotnet/doc/3.8/)

> Converts this BLP Datetime object into System.DateTime object.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime px_close_dt = fields.GetElementAsDatetime("PX_CLOSE_DT").ToSystemDateTime();
```